# Pandas - Merge Two Dataframes - sum across column

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to merge two dataframes (call them DF1 & DF2) that basically look like the below.  My goal is:

- I want open/close/low/high to all come from DF1.
- I want numEvents and Volume = DF1 + DF2.
- In cases where DF2 has rows that don't exist in DF1, I want open/close/low/high to be NaN (so I can later backfill them), and numEvents and Volume to come from DF2 as is.

Any help is much appreciated!

[image]

Comment: num_events and volume are present in both dfs?

Comment: Please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) on how to ask good pandas questions and [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/487339) on why posting images instead of text is disfavoured.

Answer (score 0):

use `pd.merge`:

it's outer join since you want data from both dfs.

`pd.merge([A,B],how='outer', on=<mutual_key>)`

Answer (score 0):

Use the `left_on` and `right_on` attributes of `pd.merge()`. You choose the fields that you want to merge.

```
DF1.merge(DF2, how='outer', right_on=<keys>...)
```